# Consulta em duas tabelas com count

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela no mysql que tem uma quantidade de itens contratados.

Tabela `itens_contratados`

> id_contratado
>   Item
>   Qtd_contratada

Tabela `servico`, nesta informo o serviço que executei no contrato

> id_contratado

Quero fazer uma consulta que me informe assim:

```
itens_contratados.id_contratado itens_contratados.qtd_contratada servicos.qtd_servico saldo
```

Onde `qtd_servico` é igual a quantidade de registros encontrados na tabela `servico` referente ao `id_contratado` e `saldo` = `qtd_contratada` - `qtd_servico`

Comment: Seria interessante você colocar a estrutura das suas tabelas e alguns dados nesse nesse link: https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwif-r3r34bVAhXJDpAKHeI1ApoQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsqlfiddle.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFm12TxaUOyr1fCpsH3njbgA9q20A fica mais fácil para testarmos a `query` antes de colocar como resposta

Comment: ok amigo, mas não posso colocar a estrutura da tabela. Quero algo genérico.... esses dados não são minha tabela. Quero entender a lógica

Comment: Ok, vou fazer algo genérico

Comment: Obrigado! Pela Ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você pediu nos comentários da sua pergunta, segue abaixo uma `query` genérica usando `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id_contratado, a.Qtde_contratada, COUNT(b.id_contratado) qtde_servico, (a.Qtde_contratada - COUNT(b.id_contratado)) saldo
FROM items_contratados a
INNER JOIN servico b ON a.id_contratado = b.id_contratado
GROUP BY a.id_contratado
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, na verdade a qtde_servico, não é um campo mas seria a quantidade de registros na tabela servico, que correspondam ao id_contratado... saldo é a a.Qtde_contratada - qtde_servico(Quantidade de registros na tabela servico).

Comment: Alterei a `query` conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: fazendo as devidas mudancas preciso de algo assim SELECT a.id_pn, a.qtd, COUNT(b.id_pn) as qtde_servico, (COUNT(b.id_pn) - qtd_servico) saldo
FROM itens_contratados a
INNER JOIN controle_contratos b ON a.id_pn = b.id_pn
GROUP BY a.id_pn só que dá erro ao subtrair por qtd_servico não é um campo

Comment: Ops, coloquei o `COUNT` na posição errada, acabei de consertar

Comment: Roberto Fagundes, sua ajuda foi de grande valor, mas meu problema é bem maior que esse. Tem como conversarmos por email?

Comment: Vou abrir outra ajuda e ser mais específico!

Comment: roberto.rfc@live.com